# Select with "like '%'" takes a lot of time

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have `CL_USER` table with varchar column `login`:

```
CREATE TABLE CL_USER (...
    `LOGIN` varchar(15) NOT NULL...
ALTER TABLE `CL_USER`
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX `CL_USER_INDEX_LOGIN`(`LOGIN`);
```

And I have a select query with filter by login. I observe a very big performance degradation with selection that contains `LIKE '%'`. Below are some measurements (3 times for every query):

```
1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CL_STATISTICS s, CL_USER u 
WHERE s.pk <= 180735 AND s.user_pk = u.pk AND s.game_type = 7 AND u.login LIKE '%'
duration: 0.409146, 0.46557125, 0.44063275

2. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CL_STATISTICS s, CL_USER u 
WHERE s.pk <= 180735 AND s.user_pk = u.pk AND s.game_type = 7
duration: 0.2063145, 0.193227, 0.21384825

3. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CL_STATISTICS s, CL_USER u 
WHERE s.pk <= 180735 AND s.user_pk = u.pk AND s.game_type = 7 AND u.login LIKE 'p%'
duration: 0.031623, 0.0364385, 0.0400135
```

That looks really weird, why query 1 and 2 are not the same?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `JOIN .. ON`, not commajoin.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the other table.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each query.  They *may* give good clues -- what indexes are used and which table is used first.  Probably `user` is used first for the 3rd query.

`s` needs `INDEX(game_type, pk)`

Is the `COUNT(*)` the same with or without the `JOIN`?  If it is the same, then the explanation is that it is unnecessarily doing the `JOIN` to make sure there is a row in both tables.

The real solution is to take more effort in building the query.  If there is no restriction on user, then don't join to `users`.